# ArrayList wrong output

Tags: java, arraylist

I just started working on Vending Machine program but I encountered a problem here.  The output is not as expected. Here is my code.

Vending Machine:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VendingMachine {


    static List<ShowMenu> menu = new ArrayList<ShowMenu>();

    public static void main(String [] args){


    System.out.println("Please choose from the menu below:");
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){

        String[] item = {"Water", "Coke" , "Diet Coke", "Iced Tea", "Swiss Chocolate", "Candy", "Chips", "Bubble Gum", "Turkish Delight"};
        int[] count = {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10};
        double[] price = {0.75,1.20,1.20,1.00,1.50,0.95,1.10,0.50,1.20};


        ShowMenu items = new ShowMenu(item, count, price);
        menu.add(items);

    }

    int k=1;

    for(ShowMenu item: menu){
        System.out.print(k +".");
        k = k + 1;
        System.out.println(item);
    }
   }
  }
```

ShowMenu:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class ShowMenu {

    public String[] item;
    public int[] count;
    public double[] price;

    public ShowMenu(String[] items, int[] count, double[] price){

        this.item = items;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;

    }


    public String toString(){
    return " " + item + " " + "$" + price;
    }
  }
```

This is the output below. I'm expecting to list down item with price such as 
1. Water   $0.75 but instead it shows another thing.

```
Please choose from the menu below:
1. [Ljava.lang.String;@5f47ff11 $[D@6fbae5f5
2. [Ljava.lang.String;@574f7121 $[D@208c5a4f
3. [Ljava.lang.String;@5e7d093a $[D@62e8ef4c
4. [Ljava.lang.String;@2ab6994f $[D@3a0b2771
5. [Ljava.lang.String;@324a897c $[D@3b8845af
6. [Ljava.lang.String;@6f9702b1 $[D@2331ebb3
7. [Ljava.lang.String;@226946d2 $[D@2da896a4
8. [Ljava.lang.String;@173a0067 $[D@60f0761a
9. [Ljava.lang.String;@4ad9d6ae $[D@239d5fe6
```

Anyone help..!!

Comment: I'd use a map for this. Would clean up your code some.

Comment: you need to override the `toString()` method properly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a loop on the whole list of products, instead on each product. This is your code fixed:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VendingMachine
{

    static List<ShowMenu> menu = new ArrayList<ShowMenu>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Please choose from the menu below:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {

            String[] item = {"Water", "Coke", "Diet Coke", "Iced Tea", "Swiss Chocolate", "Candy", "Chips",
                             "Bubble Gum", "Turkish Delight"};
            int[] count = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
            double[] price = {0.75, 1.20, 1.20, 1.00, 1.50, 0.95, 1.10, 0.50, 1.20};

            ShowMenu items = new ShowMenu(item[i], count[i], price[i]);
            menu.add(items);

        }

        int k = 1;

        for (ShowMenu item : menu)
        {
            System.out.print(k + ".");
            k = k + 1;
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}




import java.util.*;

public class ShowMenu
{

    public String item;
    public int count;
    public double price;

    public ShowMenu(String items, int count, double price)
    {

        this.item = items;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return " " + item + " " + "$" + price;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Please choose from the menu below:
1. Water $0.75
2. Coke $1.2
3. Diet Coke $1.2
4. Iced Tea $1.0
5. Swiss Chocolate $1.5
6. Candy $0.95
7. Chips $1.1
8. Bubble Gum $0.5
9. Turkish Delight $1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

`return " " + item + " " + "$" + price;`

When you return item as a string, you get the `[LJava.lang...` notation. Use `Arrays.toString(item)`

Comment: How do I use Array.toString ? Is it in a toString()..??